# Linear transformation of positive definite diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

Let $\mathbf \Psi$ denote the set of all positive definite, diagonal, nXn dimensional, real-valued matrices . Let $\mathbf \Phi$ denote the set of all positive semi-definite, diagonal, nXn dimensional, real-valued matrices .  Let $\mathbf \Pi$ denote the set of all linear transformations defined by a nXn dimensional matrix of Real numbers; Let $ \mathbf \Pi$ exclude the Zero Matrix.

Proposition 1: $\; \forall \; \Psi  \in \mathbf \Psi $, and $\; \forall \; \Pi \in \mathbf \Pi \;$, the matrix product $\; \Pi \Psi \;$ is positive definite.

Proposition 2: $\; \forall \; \Phi  \in \mathbf \Phi $, and $\; \forall \; \Pi \in \mathbf \Pi \;$, the matrix product $\; \Pi \Phi \;$ is positive semi-definite.

If Proposition 1 is false then please indicate what subset of $\Pi$ are such that $\; \Pi \Psi \;$ is positive definite.

If Proposition 2 is false then please indicate what subset of $\Pi$ are such that $\; \Pi \Phi \;$ is positive semi-definite.

Comment: According to Polya, "First comes understanding the question" (rough paraphrase). Do all the words make sense? Can you say it in your own words?

Comment: Given any matrix $A$, let $\Pi=A\Psi^{-1}$; then $\Pi\Psi=A$.